# How to create custom library and add it on Gradle

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-library

I am about to create my first custom library. I googled, but unable to find the answer of these question.

1. How to add my library on Gradle, so end user only need to write
   something like this; `compile 'com.myapp.mylib:1.0.0'`
2. I have added library in an existing project like this; Now how can i export just library  `.aar` file and not run the whole project.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Jitpack](https://jitpack.io/). If your library is open source it's free.
Or you can publish it to your local Maven, here is example using gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'com.mygroup'
version = '1.0'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file://[your local maven path here]")
        }
    }
}
```

Read more [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html).